# OpenCL: long, long4, long16... when to use?

Tags: opencl, gpgpu

I'm trying to understand the difference between working with just long, long2, long3, long4, long8, long16. Let's assume that my CL_DEVICE_PREFERRED_VECTOR_WIDTH_LONG is 2.

When should I be working with long, long2, long3, long4, long8, long16? Assume that I want my kernel to XOR a bunch of bitvectors of, say, length 500.

- If using long, I need to XOR ceil(500/64)=8 long.
- If using long2, I need to XOR ceil(500/128)=4 long2.
- If using long8, I need to XOR ceil(500/512)=1 long8.

So what would be the difference between xorring long[8], long2[4] or long8? Is there any advantage of going beyond the CL_DEVICE_PREFERRED_VECTOR_WIDTH_LONG at all?

Edit: I added a small sample script to make it more clear: the `for (int j=0; j<8; j++)` loops over a vector of length 8, and I wondered if I'd better do this for one `long8`, four `long2`s or eight `long`s.

```
while (i < to) {
    ui64[] row = rows[rowIndex];
    ui64 bitchange = i++;
    bitchange ^= i;
    rowIndex = 63-__builtin_clzll(bitchange);
    ui64 cardinality = 0;
    for (int j=0; j<8; j++) {
        curr[j] ^= row[j];
        cardinality += __builtin_popcountll(curr[j]);
    }
    popcountpolynomial[cardinality]++;
}
```

Comment: When using longN, are you XORing each of the long values, or just a single xor for the entire data structure?

Comment: I'm still not quite clear how you xor your data. Do you xor 2 (or more) `long8` vectors to get a new 500bit vector where each bit is the xor of the corresponding bits in the inputs, or do you do xor the values inside the vector (so xor 1 long8 down to one long or even one bit)?

Comment: A long8 consists of 8*64=512 bits. So, I can use the first 500 to put my vector in, and just leave the latter 12 on zero. This way I can represent my bit vectors as long8. And then if v1 and v2 are long8, v1^v2 is long8 representing the XOR of both vectors. I hope this cleared it up?

Comment: A long8 vector is still referred to by its component long values. (vect.s0 vect.s1 ... s7) I am unsure of a way to read in only part of a long8 to do the operation on the value your bit falls on. I guess it would make sense to load the long8 value into LDS if you are doing many operations on it, but if you are doing an occasional xor, it doesn't make much sense to use long8 unless you can operate on a part of the vector easily.

Comment: Ok, apparently I'm not expressing myself well. I've written down an example in plain C above. I hope it is clear now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mfa is correct aout the preferred width, but using wider vectors usually is good. The device will sequentially issue instructions to process in the widest format vectors it supports, which is good because it helps hide the latency of the operation. This is much more true on GPUs and much less true on CPUs, GPUs tend to have a lot of registers (> 1000).

Think of the preferred width as the width that guarantees you won't "waste" vector lanes on vector architecture processors - if the GPU has vector ALUs, issuing instructions that don't use the whole width (say, only use the first item in the vector), then the other lanes might go unused in that instruction, wasting potential computing power. Think of SSE where it could be doing 4 adds with one instruction, but you're only getting one number as a result because you're not using 3 of the 4 pieces of the vector.

OpenCL compilers (on vector ALU hardware) try to restructure your code to "vectorize" if you aren't using the full vector width, but obviously there are limitations to that.

Of course, only use the wider vectors when it feels natural in your algorithm. Never contort your program to try to use really wide vectors.

Using less registers is a good thing too though, if you're using too many registers, it may restrict the number of wavefronts/warps that can be run in parallel.

Using vectors can actually reduce register pressure if the auto-vectorizer fails to find a vectorized solution in scalar code, in the case that the hardware does use a vector ALU - you'll "waste" less vector lanes because more will fit in each register.

Answer (score 1):

CL_DEVICE_PREFERRED_VECTOR_WIDTH_(type) for any data type is usually the most effective size for the memory access. Many current GPU devices use a 128-bit cache line structure, which is why CL_DEVICE_PREFERRED_VECTOR_WIDTH_LONG often evaluates to 2. If you use long4, the memory operation may be broken into two smaller reads/writes on the device -- effectively blocking some threads from executing. I don't think there is an advantage to using vectors larger then the preferred size, but I can imagine a disadvantage. You should benchmark it on your device to see if this is true for you.

If the only operation you are doing is XOR, I suggest using longN (N = preferred size) and the 64-bit atomics to do the job. I hope your device supports 64 bit extended atomics. [(cl_khr_int64_extended_atomics)](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/cl_khr_int64_extended_atomics.html)

Comment: For the given length I would rather avoid using atomics instead of giving a whole bitvector to one workgroup and using local memory to combine (or maybe give one to each workitem). Atomics aren't exactly fast on gpus (look [here](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=203627#entry1289120) for numbers on fermi which is afaik already faster when using atomics then older nvidia cards (no clue about amd though))